# Using the system command

Tags: c

I am using the following system command to call ffmpeg im my c program:

```
system("ffmpeg -t 10 -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -r 30 -i /dev/video0 -f mp4 /home/somepath/webcam.mp4");
system("ffmpeg -i /home/somepath/webcam.mp4 -r 1 -s 640x480 -f image2 foo-%03d.jpeg");
```

The problem is I need to call the second system only after the first one is completed after 10 seconds. The only way I can think of doing this is using a thread.sleep() and then call it. Is there any other more elegant method of achieving the same?

Comment: Isn't system() a blocking function call? Looks to me that you have a very elagent solution just fine. The other idea so far - use a bat file means ANOTHER kind of code that might require debugging.

Comment: system is a blocking call, so those two calls you've made are fine. But if you actually need the interval to be '10' seconds between the two calls, then 'sleep' would be the easiest.

Comment: `system` is not a command (like `ls` or `sh`) but a function built above syscalls, see my answer. And using `%d` in `system` like you do is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/

> int system ( const char * command );
>
> Execute system command
>
> Invokes the command processor to execute a command. Once the command execution has terminated, the processor gives the control back to the program, returning an int value, whose interpretation is system-dependent.

I think `system` is blocked. So you do not need `sleep`.

Answer (score 4):

Read a good book like [advanced linux programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) or [advanced unix programming](http://basepath.com/aup/).

You'll learn that basic process creation and program execution is related to [fork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and related [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).

Actually, `system(3)` is implemented by `fork` then `execve` of `/bin/sh` with `-c` then a `waitpid` or `wait`.

You could definitely do the `fork` and `execve` yourself. You may also want to handle the [SIGCHLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCHLD) signal. You don't need any thread related calls. You may be interested by [pipe(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/dup2.2.html), [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html), [sigaction(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), [pause(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pause.2.html), [nanosleep(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) syscalls etc.

I don't understand what you want to do with your first `ffmpeg` process if it exceeds ten seconds. Do you want to [kill(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/kill.2.html) it ? (Then kill first with a `SIGTERM`, then with a `SIGQUIT` and at last with a `SIGKILL`).

If you are coding a graphical program, most toolkits provide process handling functions (because it is mixed with the event loop). With GTK consider using [g_child_watch_add](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-child-watch-add) and [g_spawn_async](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-async). Qt has a `QProcess` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably write all the commands in a bat file or  shell script and call the bat file or shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I think sleep is a good way for this, no need other solution.